# Where do I find the Enterprise Library xsd file if I install Logging via Nuget?

Tags: logging, xsd, enterprise-library, nuget, nuget-package

I integrated the Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging Application Block into my project using Nuget and am getting "Could not find schema information for the element ..." messages in VS2010.  I need the EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.xsd file to eliminate these messages.  How do I find this file without actually downloading the full Enterprise Library installer?  I couldn't locate it in Nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the schema file is only available in the installer (it's not in the source code download).

You could just download the installer, open it in 7-Zip and then copy the ConfigSchema2010 file to:

```
%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas\EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.xsd
```

You still have to download the installer but at least you don't have to actually install (if you are averse to such things).  Once extracted you could manually deploy as needed to development machines.

Comment: Thanks! This worked beautifully. Note that I also had to remove the Version, Culture, and PublicKeyToken from the "type" in two of my app.config file settings to eliminate warnings. See the following for more detail: http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/29239